# Looking for a relatively low attenuating yeast with distinct Belgian flavors.

Tags: beer, yeast, fermentation, attenuation

I'm working on a recipe for a Baltic porter but would like to ferment it with a stran that produces distinct belgian flavors. The problem is that most of your belgian strains are too high attenuating. I'm wanting a strain that attenuates in the low 70%s but has great fruity esters and spicy phenols. Again, very Belgian.

And yes I have considered mashing high and just using a Belgian yeast I'm familiar with, but I'd rather find a lower attenuating yeast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glancing over the [White Labs](http://www.whitelabs.com/beer/homebrew_strains.html) and [WYeast](http://www.wyeastlab.com/hb_yeaststrain.cfm) charts, it seems that [WLP410 Belgian Wit II](http://www.whitelabs.com/beer/strains_wlp410.html) and [WYeast 3944 - Belgian Witbier](http://www.wyeastlab.com/hb_yeaststrain_detail.cfm?ID=69) have the lowest attenuation with the flavor profile that you're looking for.

I've only used  [WLP410 Belgian Wit II](http://www.whitelabs.com/beer/strains_wlp410.html) though, so that would be my recommendation. It sounds like an interesting beer :) Good luck!

Comment: Looks like the WLP410 is the one for me!! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 3):

Attenuation is far more dependent on the fermentability of the wort than the rating of the yeast.  Those yeast ratings are merely a way of comparing one yeast to another using a standardized wort, and don't really reflect the actual attenuation.  If you want low attenuation, mash at a high temp or use grains that have a high degree of unfermentability.

Comment: DOH!  I see the original post had considered my mash temp idea.  Sorry for the redundancy.